# Keycloak extension for custom signed JWT Token (Keycloak 22.0.x)

Tags: jwt, keycloak, openid-connect, access-token, signed

I want to add an extension to the Keycloak (22.0.x) a new endpoint. That endpoint shall return a signed JWT contain certain user information. This token will be persisted by a service and later used by asynchronies jobs to obtain access token.

I know how to get the user information and I know to provide them as claim of a token. But I don't find out how to get the token signed by the keycloak.

Any hint is welcome.